# Solving code duplication scenario

Tags: angular

**In Angular, what can I do to avoid *code duplication* and keep my code more *dry* in the following scenario?**

I have a definition of some *commonly used* functionality:

```
enum RepeatEnum {
    one, two
}

class BaseClass {

    public repeatProperty: RepeatEnum = RepeatEnum.one;

    repeatMethod() {
        return this.repeatProperty === RepeatEnum.two;
   }
}
```

I have a number of `x-component.ts` files that utilise this functionality:

```
export XComponent extends BaseClass implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.repeatProperty = RepeatEnum.two
    }
}
```

I have repeat code in the corresponding `x-component.html` files of the following form:

```
<div class="repeatHtml" *ngIf="repeatMethod()">
   It's Two!
</div>
```

**What can I do to avoid having to duplicate this `html` in new components?**

Is there a way to move this block of html into a separate "template", while maintaining the underlying component logic?

Comment: let me know if any help required in understanding

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to extract component out of that common html.

My mean to say if there is html part which is keep repeating in you angular application, I suggest extract html in new component and put that component in your shared module. and use that component every where.

Idea behind component in angular is , each component is adding new custom HTML tag that you can use in you html repeatedly like other HTML tags div,table etc.

So when create new component it becomes one tag that you can use in you application places where you required it.

Comment: Yes, but that shared component would not have access to the `repeatProperty` that is used by `repeatMethod()`?

Comment: @Ben - your shared component will have input property and it will receive value from parent ...if component itself can generate value then there is no need of input property ..hope you got my point